# Does anybody with AdventureWorks experience able to help me with a question I can't seem to solve?

Tags: sql, adventureworks

I'm having trouble with AdventureWorks and am trying to solve a question. FYI it is for homework so I would appreciate if possible not to give me the answer. All I need is a push in the right direction.

The question I am trying to answer states: **List the products that only have a primary photo.** The following questions should be answered with a single query. Each question must be answered with sub queries, no Joins or Unions of any kind. Every answer works with multiple tables.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT p.Name
FROM Production.Product p
WHERE ProductID IN (
            SELECT ppp.ProductID 
            FROM Production.ProductProductPhoto ppp
            WHERE [Primary] = 1);
```

I know that I have selected everything with a primary photo, but I am unsure as to how I can filter out any products with multiple photos...

Any help would be great,
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `Production.ProductProductPhoto` table can have multiple records for a product since a product can have lots of photos of it. There will be 1 primary photo, and N non-primary photos.

You can write a subquery to find all the records in `Production.ProductProductPhoto` that have only 1 `ProductPhotoID` per `ProductID`, AND that record must have `Primary=1`. That should give you a list of `ProductID` values that you can then use for a query against `Production.Product`

Your query currently returns all the primary photo records for each product, but it does not address that part needed that determines if the product only has that single photo record.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will definitely take what you replied into account when I try it again after work tonight. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hi I think I may have solved my problem just wondering if my thinking is correct.

Comment: `SELECT p.Name
FROM Production.Product p
WHERE p.ProductID IN (
  SELECT COUNT(ph.ProductPhotoID)
  FROM Production.ProductProductPhoto ph
  WHERE [Primary] = 1
  GROUP BY ph.ProductID
  HAVING COUNT(ph.ProductPhotoID) =1);`

Comment: @AlexanderMaynard Not quite. Your subquery will return a number (since it is `SELECT COUNT()`), not a list of IDs, correct? In that case, your `WHERE p.ProductID IN ()` wouldn't return anything.

Comment: since all 504 rows for the `Production.ProductProductPhoto` table have a Primary of 1, I decided to look in the `Production.ProductPhoto` table and found that a  `ProductPhotoID = 1` meant that there were no images available for the small and large photo gif. So I tried this instead(as seen above). Thanks again for your last response.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.Name, p.ProductID
FROM Production.Product p
WHERE EXISTS ( 
        SELECT pp.ProductID 
        FROM Production.ProductProductPhoto pp
        WHERE pp.ProductID = p.ProductID
        AND EXISTS (
                SELECT ph.ProductID
                FROM Production.ProductProductPhoto ph
                WHERE ph.ProductPhotoID = pp.ProductPhotoID
                AND ph.ProductPhotoID = 1)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your assumption of, photoID of 1 means there is no photo, It would be easier to present it as

```
Select Name
from Production.Product p
Where  p.ProductID in 
    (Select pp.ProductID
    From Production.ProductProductPhoto pp
    Where pp.ProductPhotoID = 1)
```

I ran you're against mine and the rows have the same count of 346